# Transparent toolbar and statusbar

Tags: android, toolbar, transparent, statusbar

I have different activities in my project with listview in it. I am using app compact v7 and following material design.My requirement is to shown transparent toolbar and statusbar like iOS and when user will scroll the listeview towards up. listview should be visible behind the toolbar and actionbar. Please let me know how can i do this. I tried a lot of solution but could not achieve the desired o/p.

Comment: Do you want the toolbar to be solid color then animate to transparent?

Answer (score 1):

**Styles**

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**XML Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbarAdd"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (don't do the optional step #5 in your case):

[Unable to make toolbar transparent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529107/unable-to-make-toolbar-transparent-in-android/30876993#30876993)